# Remove specific entry from list (beginner in c#)

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I have a simple static inventory class which is a list of custom class Item. I am working on a crafting system and when I craft something I need to remove the required Items from my inventory list.

I tried to create a method that I can call which takes an array of the items to remove as a parameter, but its not working.

I think its because the foreach loop doesn't know which items to remove? I am not getting an error messages, it just doesn't work. How can I accomplish this?

```
public class PlayerInventory: MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Texture2D tempIcon;

    private static List<Item> _inventory=new List<Item>();

    public static List<Item> Inventory 
    {
        get { return _inventory; }
    }

    public static void RemoveCraftedMaterialsFromInventory(Item[] items) 
    {
        foreach(Item item in items) 
        {
            PlayerInventory._inventory.Remove(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the function that shows what items will be removed:

```
    public static Item[] BowAndArrowReqs()
{
    Item requiredItem1 = ObjectGenerator.CreateItem(CraftingMatType.BasicWood);
    Item requiredItem2 = ObjectGenerator.CreateItem(CraftingMatType.BasicWood);
    Item requiredItem3 = ObjectGenerator.CreateItem(CraftingMatType.String);

    Item[] arrowRequiredItems = new Item[]{requiredItem1, requiredItem2, requiredItem3};

    return arrowRequiredItems;
}
```

And here is where that is called:

THis is within the RecipeCheck static class:

```
PlayerInventory.RemoveCraftedMaterialsFromInventory(RecipeCheck.BowAndArrowReqs());
```

Comment: Assuming that "not working" means "items are not removed", then: Does `Item` correctly implement [`Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx)? That code should work (although see [`List.RemoveAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx) which is better suited here) to remove items from the list otherwise. Then again, the issue/bug could always be somewhere else ..

Comment: Hmm.. No I am not using that Equals code (first time I have actually seen that actually hah) Yes you are correct that "not working" means no items are removed.

Comment: where are `Item[] items` come from?

Comment: @MikeDavis If you don't implement Equals then *object-identity equality* will be used  for the comparison. This will never work for two different objects. All standard Collections rely on *value equality* which is implemented via `Equals`.

Comment: They come from a function that is called. I will update and post it

Comment: @user2246674 thoughts on a different implementation? How can I find those specific items and remove them?

Comment: @MikeDavis If it's merely a matter of implementing Equals, then do so. It needs to be done in [most] any case.

Comment: Ok sounds like I need to learn about how equals works and read up on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I like Jame's answer (and it sufficiently covers the contracts), I will talk on how one might implement this equality and make several observations.

For starts, in the list returned there may be *multiple* objects of the same type - e.g. BasicWood, String. Then there needs to be a *discriminator* used for each new object.

It would be bad if `RemoveCraftedMaterialsFromInventory(new [] { aWoodBlock })` to remove a Wood piece in the same way that two wood pieces were checked ("equals") to each other. This is because being "compatible for crafting" isn't necessarily the same as "being equals".

One simple approach is to assign a unique ID (see [`Guid.NewGuid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx)) for each *specific* object. This field would be used (and it could be used exclusively) in the Equals method - however, now we're back at the initial problem, where each *new object is different from any other*!

So, what's the solution? Make sure to use equivalent (or identical objects) when removing them!

```
List<Item> items = new List<Item> {
    new Wood { Condition = Wood.Rotten },
    new Wood { Condition = Wood.Epic },
};
// We find the EXISTING objects that we already have ..
var woodToBurn = items.OfType<Wood>
    .Where(w => w.Condition == Wood.Rotten);
// .. so we can remove them
foreach (var wood in woodToBurn) {
   items.Remove(wood);
}
```

Well, okay, that's out of the way, but then we say: "How can we do this with a Recipe such that Equals isn't butchered and yet it will remove *any* items of the given type?"

Well, we can either do this by using LINQ or a List method that supports predicates (i.e. `List.FindIndex`) or we can implement a special Equatable to only be used in this case.

An implementation that uses a predicate might look like:

```
foreach (var recipeItem in recipeItems) {
    // List sort of sucks; this implementation also has bad bounds
    var index = items.FindIndex((item) => {
       return recipeItem.MaterialType == item.MaterialType;
    });
    if (index >= 0) {
       items.RemoveAt(index);
    } else {
       // Missing material :(
    }
}
```

Comment: Whew I feel like this is a really good answer, so thank you! I am going to read it a couple more times and let it sink in haha.

Comment: The guid peice is very interesting, had never heard of that before. But I guess like you said you still cant see if they are equal because they are different. Then I get lost from there but still digesting. :)

Answer (score 0):

If class `Item` doesn't implement `IEquatable<Item>` and  the `bool Equals(Item other)` method, then by default it will use `Object.Equals` which checks if they are the same object. (not two objects with the same value --- the *same* object).

Since you don't say how `Item` is implemented, I can't suggest how to write it's Equals(), however, you should also override `GetHashCode()` so that two Items that are Equal return the same hash code.

UPDATE (based on comments):
Essentially, List.Remove works like this:

```
  foreach(var t in theList)
  {
         if (t.Equals(itemToBeRemove))
              PerformSomeMagicToRemove(t);
  }
```

So, you don't have to do anything to the code you've given in your question.  Just add the Equals() method to Item.

Comment: OK I see what you mean. They would literally have to be the same Object, which of course they are not. If I make class Item inherit from IEquatable, then I could simply say if item.Equals(Item) and then if true remove that item?

Comment: AH I see its a bool, I think I get it now. I just need to figure out how to implement Iequatable in unity, seems to be harder that it should be for some reason.

Comment: Ah what. If I mark another answer correct it says this one is not correct?! boo... :P